# list all computers on a network with cmd or C#

Tags: c#, networking, ip, psexec, subnet

I need to get a list of all the computers on the network

The network is split into two local networks. An admin network and an education network, and then under each of the admin and education networks there are sub nets for each campus. So there is an Admin and an Education Domain controller for each campus.

I can run "net view" in command prompt on each sub net to get a list of all the computers but I would like to be able to just run this on one server, or if I need to two servers (one for the admin network and one for the education network)

I know there are applications like nmap that can do this but I want to be able to use built in windows feature like "net view" or write something my self.

Additional Details:
I have a program (written by a previous developer) that runs as a background service and on each computer that launches a popup and plays an .mp3 file when a fire alarm is set off. I want to get ride of this program and use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to launch the popup and play the message instead of having the service installed on every computer. I have PsExec working but need to get a list of all the computers.

Comment: Side note: push model (as you trying to build with psExec) may not satisfy original requirement why it was done using pull... While interesting to do it may be good idea to check official requirements first...

Answer (score 10):

Find All Active/Used IP Addresses on Your Network
There is a really neat way that you can quite easily find all active/used IP Addresses on your network without the need for any third party applications or worse, pinging each IP Address manually.

Open the Command Prompt and type in the following:

FOR /L %i IN (1,1,254) DO ping -n 1 192.168.10.%i | FIND /i "Reply">>c:\ipaddresses.txt

Change 192.168.10 to match you own network.

Comment: What does the `(1, 1, 254)` do here?

Comment: It's a cmd's FOR loop. First "1" is the starting point, next "1" is the increment, "254" is the point at which loop will stop.
In other words: `for(int i=0; i<=254; i++)`

Comment: Question: Can you use the computer's own IP to get the network mask?

Comment: "or worse, pinging each IP Address individually."

 Isn't that technically pinging each address individually? I believe you may mean "pinging each address from 1-254 *manually*". The code you posted pings each one individually, it's just that the for loop does it for you. In addition to that, each ping takes roughly 3 seconds to complete, resulting in almost 13 minutes to get to the final address. In this context (a fire alarm), 13 minutes is grossly unacceptable. Although this is a valid answer for the *question*, it does not fit the *context* of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a batch file that runs `Net View` and dumps it to a text file.  From that you can do whatever you want with that data.  This could run daily as a scheduled task, or manually when new machines are added.

Comment: On large networks this won't necessarily give you all of the available computers.  I get about 53 computers from my local network of ~200... generally only those that are configured a specific way.  Short of doing a ping scan you can't realistically get a full accounting of local devices.

Comment: It does have the possibility of becoming an issue.  (I have never looked at it that closely)  I would think on a domain it would be pretty reliable though.

Comment: Unfortunately it's dependent on the computers broadcasting browser messages and so on, which most of my machines aren't set up to do.  Depending on configuration you can get better or worse results, including nothing (local machine included) being included in the results :(

Comment: Hi user2301728, I am trying to keep all the code in one place to make it easier for anyone that comes along after me, but I think I probably will do something similar to what you have suggested if there isn't any other way.

Hi Corey, thanks for the warning about the net view not necessarily giving all the computers, I had thought the list it was returning seemed a bit shorter than I was expecting, so I will test it and compare the list it is giving me to the list the current service is giving. If it isn't giving a correct list then I will try just pinging every possible ip...

Comment: Any time!  If it were my project, I would think that an NMAP ping sweep as mentioned in your original post would be the direction I would head.  You can still schedule that with scheduled tasks, or any other way you choose.  No point in reinventing the wheel :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how large the network is that you work on but you could try querying Active Directory. Check this link out below for more of an idea.

[List of computers in Active Directory that are online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778623/list-of-computers-in-active-directory-that-are-online)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

Code C#:

```
// Get host name from current network
String strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
List<string> machinesName = new List<string>();    

// Find host by name
IPHostEntry iphostentry = Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName);

// Enumerate IP addresses from current network
int nIP = 0;
foreach(IPAddress ipaddress in iphostentry.AddressList)
{
    host = Dns.GetHostByAddress(ipaddress);//ip Address is to be specified machineName
    //Add machine name into the list        
    machinesName.Add(host.HostName);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do what he asked for, this is getting a list of the ips his own computer has. He wants to get a list of all other computers in the network

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :-
using C# code:-
/* must include these libraries */

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets; 

 private void GetIP()
    {
        Process netUtility = new Process();

        netUtility.StartInfo.FileName = "net.exe";

        netUtility.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        netUtility.StartInfo.Arguments = "view";

        netUtility.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        netUtility.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        netUtility.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        netUtility.Start();



        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(netUtility.StandardOutput.BaseStream, netUtility.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding);



        string line = "";

        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            if (line.StartsWith("\\"))
            {

                listBox1.Items.Add(line.Substring(2).Substring(0, line.Substring(2).IndexOf(" ")).ToUpper());

            }

        }

        streamReader.Close();
        netUtility.WaitForExit(1000);

    }
```

For more details, I had made a Windows chatting App where i'am using this code to get list of the system names in my network. You can check there how it works. Link is https://github.com/akki9c/wifi-chating/blob/master/chatSample/chatSample/Form1.cs